# Issue in reading UTF-16 text file using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, utf-16

I am trying to read UTF-16 file using pyspark dataframe. While reading, if there is a space in the file, it is showing as box while displaying using df.display(). How to read this properly?

```
df = spark.read.option("delimiter","|") \
        .option("header","True") \
        .option("encoding", "UTF-16") \
        .option("multiline",'True') \
        .csv(f"<<path>>")
```

**Error Screenshot:**
[Space in file while reading through dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5OdP.png)

Comment: Does all of the remaining data show up as desired? Then my guess is that the "space" isn't just a traditional U+0020, but some other unicode space (or even a character that's not rendered visibly but is not really a space). Have you inspected the input file with a hexeditor to investigate?

Comment: Let me check it with Hexeditor

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this syntax

```
.option("encoding", "UTF-16")
```

Comment: I actually mentioned as UTF-16 only, like how you mentioned. Here wrongly typed, updated it now. This is not working

Comment: you're sure that the input data are encoded in UTF-16 ?

Comment: I opened the file in notepad++. At the right side bottom, it was showing UTF-16 LE

Comment: Try to save the dataframe into a file and check the output encoding. It may be related to the display method

Comment: It worked. While saving it came properly